# special chars in CGI Python \\xe4 not ä

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, cgi, special-characters

a Python cgi script receive a POST XMLHttpRequest with content type: *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*. The values are not encoded.
This looks like this:

```
  xhr.open("POST", "URL", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.send('RID=123&RName=Bäcker');
```

in Chromes developer Tools, the Form Data in Datasource looks like this in source:

RID=123&RName=Bäcker

or like this in parsed view:

**RID**: 123

**RName**: Bäcker

The python3 script get the form in a fieldstorage:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3    
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import cgi
myform = cgi.FieldStorage()
print(str(myform["RName"].value))
```

the print output is B\xe4cker?
I have tried to use .encode('iso-8859-1') or decode('utf-8') but it is not very successfull.

How can i change the encoding or code type that it will be displayed correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding encoding to `str()` function:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3    
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import cgi
myform = cgi.FieldStorage()
print(str(myform["RName"].value, encoding = 'iso-8859-1'))
```

Comment: after some tries, this lead me to a working solution.  i have tested on desktop \w chrome and the issues appeared on ios safari. Seems there are some differences between the forms sended by different devices..... this code `str(myform["RName"].value).encode("utf-8")` did the job by the end